# android studio open activity with button

Tags: android

I'm in the process of making a never have in ever app. where there is a start page with a button that has to get you on to a new page but can't figure out why it doesn't work

the startpage you only need to see when you open the app and when you push the button "igang!" which is the start button, it must send you to a random page with a question and all the questions have their own button called "Næste" which is meaning next that will get you to the next random question, just never start the page again,

what can I do??

here are photos of my app

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eE9z.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q898M.jpg

```
<Button
        android:text="@string/igang"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="120sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/american_captain"
        android:layout_width="262dp"
        android:background=
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you include your buttons `onClick` method here?

Comment: I've tried it from these videos

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bgIUdb-7Rqo

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ueIhlDj2cs&t=83s

Comment: Could you explain here what have you done so far? As much as possible, we want to immediately see the details in your question and not in another site. For the random page part, I don't think it's a good idea to make a hundred `Activity` for a single question. Make a single question `Activity` that content the list of questions with it's answer together then make a code for randomizing them and setting to the `Activity`'s UI.

Comment: how do you do it then ?? I'm a total beginner

Comment: I made a video showing my app. where i show what i need to do
https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=zMgMN2yfHj0

Answer (score 0):

Just put every question in a single line in a text file in assets and name it file.txt or whatever you want then add this code to your activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //my button and textview declaration
    final TextView myTextView = findViewById(R.id.mytext);
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View p1)
            {
                List<String> list_to_array = new ArrayList<>();
                try{
                    //read file.txt in assets..
                    InputStream input_stream = getAssets().open("file.txt");
                    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(input_stream);
                    BufferedReader buffered_reader = new BufferedReader(reader);
                    String line;
                    //add every question to the list
                    while((line = buffered_reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        list_to_array.add(line);
                    }
                } catch(IOException error)
                {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
                //convert the list to an array of string and it's length will be the size of the list

                String[] questions = list_to_array.toArray(new String[list_to_array.size()]);
                //set a random text (question) to the TextView..
                myTextView.setText(questions[new Random().nextInt(questions.length)]);
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: I made a video showing my app. where i show what i need to do
https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=zMgMN2yfHj0

Comment: I need more information about where do you store the text of every question, in a text file in assets?, or in strings.xml in res folder?, or?

Comment: It's better if you store every question in a line in a text file in assets

Comment: I changed the answer, just put every question in a single line in a text file in assets and name it "file.txt" or whatever you want then add this code in the answer